# hyperlink for citations using harvard style

Tags: citing

I am following a prescribed template for authoring my thesis, and it has `\usepackage{harvard}`. I would like hyperlinks to my citations, for instance, `\cite{ref}` should point to the particular reference in my reference list. I am using `\usepackage{hyperref}`, but the links are not created. Am I missing something? Please suggest.

TIA
Vinod

P.S: Here is the .tex file with all the included packages

```
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%----------------- LaTeX packages ------------------------------
% The package loading order is important here.
% fancyhdr must come before the main usqthesis.sty
% hyperref should after usqthesis.sty
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}           % heading format
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{thesis}          % dissertation style file
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Note that the setpagesize=false is necessary to stop
% hyperref resetting the page size back to Letter
\usepackage{hyperref}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Use the first here for colored links in the PDF output file
% use the second for printed output (black text only)
% Note also that the setpagesize=false is necessary to stop
% hyperref resetting the page size back to Letter

\hypersetup{setpagesize=false, a4paper=true, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue,citecolor=black}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{psfrag}             % LaTeX fragments in PostScript drawings
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------- AMS special math symbol packages ---------------
% the following is one of the `ams' packages
\usepackage{amsmath}    % math symbols like $\boldsymbol{\mu}$

% another `ams' package
% math font symbols like $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{R}$
\usepackage{amsfonts}

% another `ams' package
% math relations like $\triangleq \therefore$
\usepackage{amssymb}
%-------------- end AMS special math symbol packages -----------


%---------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{harvard}            % referencing format. Use with \bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % including eps or pdf graphics
\usepackage{url}                % format web, email, and file names
\usepackage{caption}            % figure captions
% Vinod
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{pdftex}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%Vinod: graphics extensions and path
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% some options which should be set up for the caption package
\captionsetup{margin=2ex, font=small, labelsep=colon, aboveskip=2mm, belowskip=2mm}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% these are for *extended* use only
%\usepackage{listings}           % use only if you have program code
%                                % see Appendix C
%\usepackage{pdfpages}           % use only if you have other documents to include
%                                % see Appendix D
%\usepackage{rotating}           % rotating objects - see rotated column headings example in design.tex
%--------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{a4pdf}              % set PDF output sizes. Must be the last package
%--------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% include only certain chapters whilst under development
%\includeonly{chap2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% packages added by Vinod
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{textcomp}

%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%--------------------- Customization ---------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand{\thesistitle}{title}

\renewcommand{\thesisauthor}{author}
\renewcommand{\thesisstudentnum}{student number}
\renewcommand{\thesismonth}{November}
\renewcommand{\thesisyear}{2014}

\renewcommand{\universityname}{university name}
\renewcommand{\facultyname}{faculty name}
\renewcommand{\thesistype}{thesis}
\renewcommand{\thesisprincipalsupervisor}{supervisor 1} % your  principal supervisor
\renewcommand{\thesisassistantsupervisor}{supervisor 2} % second supervisor. If none, leave blank.
\renewcommand{\thesisdegree}{Doctor of Philosophy}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\thesistitlepage        % Generate the title page.
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\include{abstract}          % abstract of the thesis
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\include{publications}      % associated publications (if any)
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% disclaimer not used with research theses??
%\thesisdisclaimerBENG       % disclaimer page
%\thesisdisclaimerMETC       % disclaimer page
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\thesiscertificationpage    % certification page
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\include{acknow}            % acknowledgements
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% may want this if you want to ensure table of contents is on
% the right (ie odd numbered page) if printing two-sided
\mbox{}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\include{notation}           % mathematical notation used in thesis
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\include{acronyms}           % acronyms & abbreviations used in thesis
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\include{nomencl}          % nomenclature or terminology (if required)
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\include{intro}
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% Vinod: include each chapter as and when
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\include{chap2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------------------------------------------
%****** for both a list of references and a bibliography *******
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------

%
%---------------------------------------------------------------
% The bibliography (thesis.bib file)

% this changes the title from Bibliography to References
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

% the \cite{} commands in the text pull in all the references
% actually cited. This command pulls in all references regardless.
%\nocite{*}

% specify the bibliography file usqthesis.bib
%\bibliography{thesis}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% this is for the standard list of references - thesis.bib
% change heading as you wish
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{List of References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{thesis}


%---------------------------------------------------------------


%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% this is for the bibliography (additional references)
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography}
%\input{bibliography.bbl}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% \chapter is actually an appendix from now on...
\appendix
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\include{appenda}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
%\include{appendb}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% *extended* use only
%\include{appendc}        % shows how to include code - optional
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% *extended* use only
%\include{appendd}        % shows how to include other documents - optional
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
% *extended* use only
%\include{appende}        % shows how to include a timeline - optional
%---------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the information

Comment: I am using the above file, and when I use \cite{ref} in an included file, say chapter 2, I do not get a hyperlink to the entry in List of References. Hope the question is clearer now.